# Microdata - Should we use rdf.data-vocabulary.org or Schema.org

Tags: html, seo, microdata

As I said in my title, I ask which (or maybe the both) of data-vocabulary or Schema.org we should use ?

I know that Schema.org is the one recommanded by google, but i can see data-vocabulary on many website. And I even see the both on a single page !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. I wouldn't mix and match!

I will say however that (personally, anecdotally) I have seen better search results from well implemented schema'd sites than other microformats.

Comment: Thank you. I finally used Both, depends on the case. For exemple the Breadcrumb of data-vocabulary was realy easyer to implement (and especially well documented on google recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking Schema.org. For these reasons:

On Google's own rich snippits page they recommend it: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506?hl=en

> New! schema.org lets you mark up a much wider range of item types on
>   your pages, using a vocabulary that Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! can
>   all understand. Find out more. (Google still supports your existing
>   rich snippets markup, though.)

This Google FAQ is also very supportive: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158?hl=en

> schema.org is a collaboration by Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! to
>   improve the web by creating a structured data markup schema supported
>   by major search engines.

So it would seem this is the one Google is pushing now, and they claim support by 3 major search engines too.

Comment: Schema.org is the new 'standard'.

http://www.data-vocabulary.org/ is actually referring to the schema.org site.

I believe it's a superset of the original data vocabulary.